# Postgres Time Averaged Data

Tags: sql, postgresql

We use Postgres to record the data from our process. An example of our database is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Data
("time_stamp" timestamp, "pressure" numeric, "temperature" numeric, "flow" numeric);

INSERT INTO Data
("time_stamp", "pressure", "temperature", "flow")
VALUES
('2016-05-12 20:42:24', 97.68, 9.02564, 2.24664),
('2016-05-12 20:42:25', 97.68, 9.02564, 2.24054),
('2016-05-12 20:42:26', 122.1, 9.01832, 2.24054),
('2016-05-12 20:42:27', 122.1, 9.01099, 2.23443),
('2016-05-12 20:42:28', 97.68, 9.01099, 2.23443),
('2016-05-12 20:42:29', 122.1, 9.01099, 2.24054),
('2016-05-12 20:42:30', 97.68, 9.01099, 2.23443),
('2016-05-12 20:42:31', 122.1, 9.01099, 2.23443),
('2016-05-12 20:42:32', 122.1, 9.01832, 2.24054),
('2016-05-12 20:42:33', 122.1, 9.01832, 2.23443);
```

What I am trying to do is get Postgres (using pgAdminIII) to generate an averaged data for an arbitrary time slice, say 5 seconds. It would output an averaged time, pressure, temperature and flow column for that five second slice. There would be two entries for this data, with the time entries being '2016-05-12 20:42:26' and '2016-05-12 20:42:31'.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution, that's not the best, but kinda works.

```
SELECT timestamp without time zone '1970-01-01' + cast(avg(extract(epoch from time_stamp))::text as interval),
       sub.press,
       sub.temp,
       sub.flow 
FROM data d join (
     SELECT
           (extract(seconds from time_stamp)/5)::integer as num,
           avg(pressure) as press,
           avg(temperature) as temp,
           avg(flow) as flow
      FROM
           data
      group by 1) sub on sub.num=(extract(second from d.time_stamp)/5)::integer
group by sub.press,sub.temp,sub.flow
order by 1
```

The sub select selects data from Data table and groups it by 5 seconds. The outer select is needed for the timestamp to get "averaged". I think this should be much easier to do with a function.

Edit:
Here's the function I wrote for this. Assuming there is only one row per second.

You need to create a custom type first:

```
CREATE TYPE t_data AS
(
  time_stamp timestamp,
  pressure numeric,
  temp numeric,
  flow numeric);
```

This is the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dataCheck ( timeInterval integer ) RETURNS setof t_data AS $BODY$
DECLARE
  pressure numeric[];
  temp numeric[];
  flow numeric[];
  rec record;
  i integer default 1;
  ret t_data;
BEGIN
  for rec in select * from data order by time_stamp
  loop
    pressure[i]=rec.pressure;
    temp[i]=rec.temp;
    flow[i]=rec.flow;

    if i=(timeInterval/2 + case when timeInterval%2 <> 0 then 1 else 0 end) then
      ret.time_stamp=rec.time_stamp;
    end if;
    if i=timeInterval then
      i=0;
      ret.pressure=avg((select avg(a) from unnest(pressure) as a));
      ret.temp=avg((select avg(a) from unnest(temp) as a));
      ret.flow=avg((select avg(a) from unnest(flow) as a));
      return next ret;
    end if;

    i=i+1;
  end loop;

return ;

end;$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And this is how you execute it:

```
SELECT * from dataCheck(5);
```

The function will return averaged data every "5" rows.

Comment: What function would you recommend? I tried the code, and it does not work well with my entire data set.

Comment: For some reason yesterday, my data output wasn't exactly every second, it skipped 25 seconds over the course of the entire day. How does this code handle that situation when there isn't an entry each second?
I also used the function `SELECT * from dataCheck(300) WHERE TIME_STAMP::DATE='YESTERDAY';` to apply this to yesterday's data file. The first time stamp averages out to be 00:04:20 and I was expecting it to be 00:02:30 or so.

Comment: Is there also a way to see exactly the range it is using for the average?

Comment: It doesn't handle that, it's a hand written function. I can't help you without actually seeing the data.

Comment: How do I send it to you?